# More light-weighted method to perform two blocking IO calls in C++

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

I'm implementing a client application with C++ and there is a tight constraint on CPU core resources.

Basically I have two separated IO routines to call, saying the two tasks. These two tasks are both blocking API calls which basically are reading something from the network and return the result. The two tasks can be executed simultaneously (i.e. they don't share any resources and don't depend on each other) but I have only one CPU core to execute the two tasks.

I'm currently using two threads, one for each task. I'm asking if there is any more elegant way that can boost the performance?

Comment: check boost.asio https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.asio

Comment: You could look at [select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html).

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick comment. The problem is that, the functions (APIs, precisely) to call are provided by some vendor, which cannot be modified. Every time I call the function I would wait at least 10ms for the return, which is annoying but I've no choice. What I know from IDA is it actually uses select() but does have some timeout on remote server...

Comment: It's not easy to go from blocking io to asynchronous io. In the worst case it requires a rewrite. Someone would need intimate knowledge of the vendor API or functions to give better help.

Answer (score 1):

There's no other way than with two threads if you're unable to modify the layer beneath the vendor API. If the two functions must be called, and if they will block, then you must have two threads to execute them concurrently (in the same process).